# 503 Service unavailable in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

Our application is running google app engine with the java version 1.7, google could endpoints- 1.9.38 version. 
Everything was fine till last 5 days, but now we are getting 503 service unavailable for all the apis.

Cron jobs are running fine, but all cloud endpoints are unavailable.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: can you help me in finding the reason for Service unavailable error ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google App Engine Application Suddenly Stopped Working, returning 503](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312107/google-app-engine-application-suddenly-stopped-working-returning-503)

Answer (score -1):

You must be receiving these 503 errors because you are using a [deprecated version](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/) of Google Cloud Endpoints. You are currently in V1 and need to migrate to V2. Please review this document which describes [how to migrate an existing Cloud Endpoints 1.0 app to 2.0 in Java](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/migrating).